# How to find confidence intervals when not a normal population

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

## What I know:

r.v. $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim i.i.d \ Po(\lambda)$.
From the central limit theorem, it follows that
$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \lambda) \xrightarrow{L} \mathcal{N}(0, \lambda).
$$
The following follows when a variance stabilization transformation is performed on it.
$$
2\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda})\xrightarrow{L} \mathcal{N}(0, 1).
$$
Let $u_{\alpha/2}$ be the upper $α/2$ point of the standard normal distribution.

Let $H_n$ be the CDF of $2\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda})$. Then, from the definition of law convergence, it follows that
$$
H_n(u_{\alpha/2}) = P(2\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}) \leq u_{\alpha/2}) \to \Phi(u_{\alpha/2}) = 1-\frac{\alpha}{2} \\
\therefore P(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda} \leq \frac{u_{\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}) \to 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}
$$

## Question:

**Why does this hold true?**
$$
P(|\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}| \leq \frac{u_{\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}) \to 1-\alpha.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the complement of $\mathbb P\left(2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}\right) \leq u_{\alpha/2}\right) \to \Phi(u_{\alpha/2}) = 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$ you get $\mathbb P\left(2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}\right) \gt u_{\alpha/2}\right) \to 1-\Phi(u_{\alpha/2}) = \frac{\alpha}{2}$

and similarly for the other tail you get $\mathbb P\left(2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}\right) \lt -u_{\alpha/2}\right) \to \Phi(-u_{\alpha/2}) = \frac{\alpha}{2}$

and, since they are disjoint events, you can find the probability of their union by summing the individual probabilities $\mathbb P\left(\left|2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}\right)\right| \gt u_{\alpha/2}\right) \to \alpha$

and for its complement $\mathbb P\left(\left|2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}\right)\right| \leq u_{\alpha/2}\right) \to 1-\alpha$

which with division by $2\sqrt{n}>0$ gives $\mathbb P\left(\left|\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}\right| \leq \frac{u_{\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}\right) \to 1-\alpha$.

Comment: From the CDF definition, I can see that it would be $\mathbb{P}(2\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}) \leq -u_{\alpha/2}) \to \alpha/2$, but why would it be $\mathbb{P}(2\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}) < -u_{\alpha/2}) \to \alpha/2$?

Comment: @ytnb I had used the symmetry of the normal distribution, but another argument is that the normal distribution is continuous.  So $\mathbb P\left(2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\bar{X}}-\sqrt{\lambda}\right) = -u_{\alpha/2}\right) \to 0$